# Matlab: Reorder 5 bytes to 4 times 10 bits RAW10

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I would like to Import a RAW10 file into Matlab. The infos are directly attachted to the jpeg file provided by the raspberry pi camera.

4 Pixels are saved as 5 bytes.

The first four bytes contain the bit 9-2 of a pixel.

The last byte contains the missing LSB.

[image: Order of the bytes and bits]

```
sizeRAW = 6404096;
sizeHeader =32768;
I = ones(1944,2592);
fin=fopen('0.jpeg','r');
off1 = dir('0.jpeg');
offset = off1.bytes - sizeRAW + sizeHeader;
fseek(fin, offset,'bof');
pixel = ones(1944,2592);
I=fread(fin,1944,'ubit10','l');

  for col=1:2592
   I(:,col)=fread(fin,1944,'ubit8','l');
   col = col+4;
  end

fclose(fin);
```

This is as far as I came yet, but it's not right.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it's not right'. What exactly is not right? What are you expecting?

Comment: Have you got a URL (link) to anything that describes the data layout in the JPEG?

Comment: There's piece of code here... https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=44918 that unpacks the RAW10 data from a JPEG into a PGM (Portable GreyMap) file that Matlab should be able to read.